# how to fix Undefined variable in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

I need update some record and this is form action in my blade

```
<form class="form-vertical" role="form" method="post" action="/projects/{{ $project->id }}/collaborators/{{ $collaborator->user()->first()->id }}">
```

My controller

```
public function update(Request $request, $projectId, $collaboratorId)
 {
    $this->validate($request, [
            'status'  => 'required',
        ]);

        DB::table('permissions')
            ->where('project_id', $projectId)
            ->where('collaborator_id', $collaboratorId)
            ->update(['status' => $request->input('status')]);

        return redirect()->back()->with('info','Your Permission has been updated successfully');



 }
```

routes

```
Route::put('projects/{projects}/collaborators/{id}',['uses'=>'ProjectCollaboratorsController@update',]);
```

when click update button generate following error

```
Undefined variable: project (View: C:\Users\Nalaka\Desktop\c\resources\views\collaborators\permissionedit.blade.php)
```

how to fix this?

Comment: I don't see where you're tried to use project variable here.

Comment: check my form action

Answer (score 0):

With your route `Route::put('projects/{projects}/collaborators/{id}',['uses'=>'ProjectCollaboratorsController@update',]);` you need to send a PUT request. Your form send a POST request.

Change your route by `Route::post` or use some javascript to send a PUT request with ajax.

Try that and let's see if there are other error after. 
Also, if there are "undefined variable", show the code around this variable.

Comment: Your method `update`make a redirect. Where is it going ? Seems the variable "project" is missing there. You could add a check in the view `@if(isset($project)` Do stuff `@endif` or fix the method to send this variable again.

Comment: I allready have this variable in My view @if(isset($permissions))
    @foreach($permissions as $permission)
and how can I add @if(isset($project)

Comment: the $project variable is the one in the form action , right ?

Comment: So, `{{ $project->id }}` could become `{{ (isset($project->id) ? $project->id : '') }}`
But I think the real problem come from the fact your variable is not resend to the view after the redirect()->back().